# Filtering nulls on grouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have the following linq to sql:

```
int someNumber = (from a in TableA.col1
                       group a by a.DateUTC.Value.ToLocalTime().Date into g
                       where TableA.col2 = Emp
                       select g).Count();
```

The above works fine.  But then DateUTC started accumulating null values, which breaks the query.  I tried this:

```
int someNumber = (from a in TableA.col1
                       group a by a.DateUTC.Value.ToLocalTime().Date into g
                       where TableA.col2 = Emp && TableA.DateUTC != null
                       select g).Count();
```

But the second query isn't filtering out nulls.  I'm guessing that is because the group comes before the where.  Is there some way to use the original query to avoid an except because DateUTC may have null values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution would be filtering *before* grouping:

```
int someNumber = (from a in TableA.col1 
                   where a.DateUTC != null 
                   group a by a.DateUTC.Value.ToLocalTime().Date into g 
                   where TableA.col2 = Emp
                   select g).Count();
```